# Применение const_cast к указателю this

Tags: c++, static-cast

В данном примере использование const_cast<Single*>(this) в классе Single безопасно/оправдано?

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};

    virtual vector<Single*> get() const = 0;
};

class Single : public Base
{
public:
    Single(): Base() {};

    vector<Single*> get() const override
    {
        return vector<Single*>{const_cast<Single*>(this)};
    }
};

class Compound : public Base
{
public:
    Compound() : Base() {};

    vector<Single*> get() const override
    {
        return _vars;
    }

private:
    vector<Single*> _vars{};
};
```

Comment: Вообще-то это нехорошо. В результате вы отдаете наружу указатель на константный объект, как на неконстантный... :( Или надо делать этот метод неконстантным, или вектор от константных указателей.

Comment: вектор константных значений - вроде я где то читал, что это нельзя?

Comment: или с указателями - другая история?

Comment: нашел про вектор и const что почитать)). Спасибо, буду избегать таких конструкций :)

Comment: `vector<const Single*>` - тут нет никакой крамолы... А избегать `const_cast` - ну, не то чтоб его вообще не надо применять, но всегда надо отдавать отчет, что именно происходит и для чего. В основном это для ситуаций, когда есть что-то написанное кем-то :), принимающее неконстантную сущность, но *гарантированно* ее не меняющую. Вот тогда...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast - Notes: изменение константного объекта, полученного в результате каста, влечёт за собой UB.